# Natural way for saying 'buffer period'

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say I am leaving for a place and, since there is a huge traffic hassle in my city, I  am leaving 2-3 hours earlier.

Can I use the following sentence to describe what I am going to do?

> I am going to the airport with the **buffer of 2-3 hours**.

Does this expression sound odd to the natives? If the answer is yes, what would a more natural way of describing it be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that the word *buffer* is perfectly appropriate, but a more natural phrasing would be

> I'm giving myself a 2-3 hour buffer to get to the airport in good time.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic disturbing! Can we say in a good time too? I have a bad habit in adding an "A" before many things in my sentences. I want to know if it is correct or not in this sentence to add an "A" before good time.

Comment: @PersianCat, the "a" wouldn't be used, typically, in that sentence.  "In good time" is idiomatic where "in a good time" would mean something different - like in a good time period, I believe.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Thanks! So I have to break this habit! :I

Answer (score 8):

I'd probably say ***margin*** rather than *buffer*:

> I'm giving myself a two- or three-hour margin to get to the airport.

Comment: Hey, we're practically twins!  :-)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does sound odd. A more natural way of saying it would be "I am going to the airport 2-3 hours early".

Comment: This may have answered OP's question, however I am still interested in the question in the title - natural phrase instead of 'buffer period'. What would it be: "I am going to the airport 2-3 hours early. These 2-3 hours is my ______"?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to Tristan's excellent answer is:

> I'm going to aim to get to the airport with 2-3 hours to spare.

Comment: That's another good way to say it.

Comment: Although I think the point is not to arrive 2-3 hours early, but to allow 2-3 for traffic such that you arrive at the "normal" time.

Comment: @Jim: In which case you could say "I'm going **to leave for** the airport with 2-3 hours to spare".

Answer (score 0):

One of my father's familiar phrases was always: ***"you have to budget for delays!"*** So I would say something like, I have budgeted in an extra two hours of travel time for possible traffic/security delays.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, while 'buffer' is a reasonable name for the period, the names I'm most familiar with would be either '**extra**', 'margin' or 'leeway', as in "I'm giving myself 2-3 hours extra to get to the airport" or "I'm giving myself 2-3 hours leeway to get to the airport".